# card doesn't look consistent on different mobile devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox, mobile-website

I am trying to improve my CSS skills by designing few components. Here, I have designed an article preview component in HTML, CSS, and JS. But the card looks small on some devices and has too much margin. But on other devices, it looks good.

How can I remove this inconsistency?

***code sandbox link :*** https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-shamir-g3zui

attaching few screenshots on different mobile emulators

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I think it looks smaller on some devices, just because you have a fixed width of 327px on the card itself. You start increasing your width only for devices with a width bigger than 1440px, while the width for an iPad Pro is 1024px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have set your card class attached to the main element to a fixed width in styles.css (width: 327px;). Use percentages for width and height to get a responsive webpage.